# Client Management DB Design - Track credit based purchases

Tags: mysql, database-design

My reservation system allows us to purchase credits for clients in terms of pre defined packages.  I'm struggling with how I record and calculate available credits.

Let's say we're talking about a car wash service. A client can have multiple cars and can purchase the following services, 'Wash and Wax' and 'Detailing'.

Client 1 has two cars, Car A and Car B.  He brings them both in and purchases:

1. Car A - 1 Wash and Wax
2. Car A - 1 Detailing
3. Car B - 10 Wash and Wax
4. Car B - 1 Detailing

This generates 4 rows in my Purchases table, one for each service purchased.

In my DB I have two related tables tracking purchases and reservations.  Table 1 Purchases, Table 2 Reservations.

In Purchases I have the following fields of note:

```
id
client_id
car_id
service_id
credits_purchased
credits_scheduled
credits_used
cart_id
```

Then in my Reservation table I have the following fields of note:

```
id
client_id
car_id
service_id
reservation_date
completed_datetime
car_in_datetime
car_out_datetime
purchase_id
```

I track the credits available by updating the Purchases table fields credits_used and credits_on_schedule as events happen.

For example, when the client makes a reservation the system adds a new record in the Reservations table, once this happens the system also runs an update query and adds +1 to the related Purchases table credits_on_schedule.  When the Reservation is updated to complete the system also updates the Purchases table and adds -1 to credits_on_schedule and +1 to credits used.  Simple math between credits_purchased, credits_used, and credits_on_schedule derive what credits are available for a client to use.

I feel like this isn't a good way to track the credits.  My question is what is a better implementation? Should I just track credits_purchased then use count queries on the Reservation table to calculate credits_used and credits_on_schedule?  Should I be using a pivot table to track?  I can't seem to wrap my head around what is the cleanest design.

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me that the design is ok in general.
A reservation can only have one purchased related to it so purchase_id field is a foreign key in Reservation table.
Nevertheless, my advise to you is to create a log system of all these record updates.
As you mentioned, as events are fired the system updates the calculated fields.
What if for some reason the system fails at a certain point? You should be able to track these events.
One way to avoid this is, as you mentioned, calculate credit_used by a count query on all completed reservations.